# access $args/params from inside method

Tags: powershell

I am working on an error handling method for my PowerShell scripts. I pass it the error via `try`/`catch` on the catch, but I want to iterate through the original params from the command line that called it in order to create an error log and error email.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# --params--
param(
  [string]$Directory,
  [string]$ArchiveDirectory,
  [string]$ErrorDirectory,
  [string]$ErrorEmailFrom,
  [string]$ErrorEmailTo,
  [string]$ErrorEmailSubject,
  [string]$ErrorSMTP,
  [string]$FTPSite,
  [string]$FTPUser,
  [string]$FTPPass,
  [string]$FTPRemoteDir
)

# list of arguments for debug
$paramList = $args

# --functions--

function Handle-MyError
{
  Write-Host "handle-error"
  Write-Host $args[0];  # this is the exception passed in

  # -Email alert-
  $subject = $ErrorEmailSubject + $FTPSite 
  # build message
  $message =  Get-Date -Format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" 
  $message += "`r`nError: " + $FTPSite + " : " + $args[0]
  $message += "`r`nParameters:`r`n" 

  # Grab each parameter value, using Get-Variable
  for ($i=0;$i -lt $paramList.Length; $i++)
  {
    $message += $paramList[$i]
  }

  # send email
  $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($ErrorSMTP)
  $smtp.Send($ErrorEmailFrom, $ErrorEmailTo, $subject, $message)

  # drop error file
  $theDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyymmdd"
  $errorFile = $ErrorDirectory + "\" + $theDate + "_ERROR.txt"
  Write-Host $errorFile
  $message | Out-File $errorFile -Append
}
```

and in my `try`/`catch`:

```
catch [Exception]
{
  Write-Host "SPOT 1"
  Handle-MyError $_.
}
```

At the top, I try to save the original `$args` as `$paramList` to loop through later, but it's not working. Inside the `Handle-MyError` method, `$args` becomes the error that is passed so I thought if I save the original `$args`as `$paramList` I could access it later, but it's wonky... Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, in order of worst to best:

Use `Get-Variable` with `Scope` parameter. Scope number can differ, but it should be at least 2 (`Script->Catch->Handle-MyError`)

```
function Handle-MyError
{
   Write-Host (Get-Variable -Name ErrorEmailFrom -ValueOnly -Scope 2)
}
```

Using `$Script:` prefix

```
function Handle-MyError
{
   Write-Host $Script:ErrorEmailFrom
}
```

Using `$PSBoundParameters`

```
# list of arguments for debug
$paramList = $PsBoundParameters

function Handle-MyError
{
   Param
   (
       $Exception,
       $Cfg
   )

   Write-Host $Cfg.ErrorEmailFrom
}

catch [Exception]
{
    Write-host "SPOT 1"
    Handle-MyError -Exception $_ -Cfg $paramList
}
```

Using splatting:

```
$paramList = $PsBoundParameters

function Handle-MyError
{
    Param
    (
        $Exception,
        $ErrorDirectory,
        $ErrorEmailFrom,
        $ErrorEmailTo,
        $ErrorEmailSubject,
        $ErrorSMTP
    )

    Write-Host $ErrorEmailFrom
}

catch [Exception]
{
    Write-host "SPOT 1"
    Handle-MyError @paramList -Exception $_
}
```

Comment: $PsBoundParameters won't work unless this is a method inside the file, right? I checked $PsBoundParameters but it doesn't contain anything. Also, when I loop through the unbound params, I literally get each word in one of the params as separate values... quite strange

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have one reusable 'foreach' that I can use in all my PS scripts to loop through and dump out all param values into an email on error for debug porpuses.

Comment: @Beau Not sure what you mean by "method inside the file". As long as you have `Param` statement, `$PSBoundParameters` should be populated with all passed parameters. You can't access `$PSBoundParameters` in debugger, though, you have to assign it to another var. beforehand in code and view that variable instead. `$paramList` in examples should do the trick.

Comment: I meant if you're calling a func from inside the file like my 'Handle-MyError' function. But I see what you mean now after some trial-error. I'll mark you as the answer and post my final code as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code after some help from @beatcracker.
I combined two pieces of the puzzle.

1. I need to save the initial params in a local var and Two, (`$paramList = $PsBoundParameters)`
2. Access this var/list using .GetEnumerator()

   ```
   # --params--
   param(
       [string]$Directory,
       [string]$ArchiveDirectory,
       [string]$ErrorDirectory,
       [string]$ErrorEmailFrom,
       [string]$ErrorEmailTo,
       [string]$ErrorEmailSubject,
       [string]$ErrorSMTP,
       [string]$FTPSite,
       [string]$FTPUser,
       [string]$FTPPass,
       [string]$FTPRemoteDir
   )
   # set params as var for debug later
   $paramList = $PsBoundParameters

   # --functions--

   function Handle-MyError
   {
       Write-Host "handle-error"
       #write-host "Exception:" $args[0];  # this is the exception passed in

       # -Email alert-

       # build subject
       $subject = $ErrorEmailSubject + " " + $FTPSite 

       # build message
       $message =  Get-Date -format s
       $message += "`r`nError Message: " + $args[0]
       $message += "`r`nParameters:`r`n" 

       $paramList.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object `
       {
           #Write-Host $_.Key "=" $_.Value
           if ($_.Key -ne "FTPPass"){
               $message += "`r`n" + $_
           }
       }
   }
   ```